# If I make a battlenet account in Australia, will I be able to swap it to US?

Tags: starcraft-2, region-lock, battle.net

I am in Australia right now and I'm thinking of making a battlenet account for the various demos they claim to have on their site (which you have to have a bnet account to see).  When I get back home I intend to buy SCII, but maybe also Diablo III when it is released, perhaps Warcraft III etc, so I'm worried about two things:

- Will I have to make a new Battlenet account or rebuy any when I get back to the States?
- Will I be able to use the American account when I next come to Australia?

I guess these are really the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Online gameplay is not limited by where you play the game, no matter *what* country you connect  to the internet from.

For Starcraft 2 specifically, the only thing that matters is what regional copy of the game you buy. Buying the NA version will connect you to the NA servers -- which may prove unbearably laggy from Australia, but won't stop you from playing it. See also: [How does the StarCraft 2 region lock work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/how-does-the-starcraft-2-region-lock-work)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Blizzard chose to not region lock SC2 in Australia: http://www.kotaku.com.au/2010/07/starcraft-ii-will-not-be-region-locked-in-australia/

But who knows what they'll do in the future with Diablo III and whatnot. I would buy the US version of the game, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I am in Europe for the summer and the regions do seem to matter for at least two things.  The ladders are grouped within a region and the website is also within a region.  I VPN'd into the states so that my purchase was automatically associated as US.  When i log into SCII it doesnt care whether I am in the states or not.  Their website, battle.net, however, does care.  If you go to the site in a different region it will not find your profile.  You can choose the region manually at the bottom of the site and it will then find your account.  If you ask me this is a bug on their site that they should fix (use the zone on the account not the IP).

I think it only matters if you are planning to play competitively in the ladders.  I could be wrong

Comment: There is no need to to use a foreign VPN when ordering: their online store will you give you the choice of which version you want.

Comment: Good to know.  I just wanted to be safe.  Though, during the release it did make a difference to availability.