# StarCraft II - Can someone in Brazil use the European Server?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the StarCraft 2 region lock work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/how-does-the-starcraft-2-region-lock-work)

I live in Europe and I have a buddy who lives in Brazil and wants to play with me on the European Server of StarCraft II, he is going to buy from the European site, in euros, he is gonna get an European Server account, get an european CDkey. Will he be able to, in Brazil, log in the European Server and play with me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as he buys the game for the same region as you are in. Currently the game is region-locked, meaning that you can't play on a different server without buying a separate copy of Starcraft 2 specifically for that region.

[Global Play is stated to be coming soon to Starcraft 2](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/7826684/Global_Play_Coming_to_StarCraft_II-12_21_2012), and I believe this applies to all versions of Starcraft 2, not just the upcoming expansion Heart of the Swarm. This feature will allow you to create new profiles on other regions, so you would be able to play with him regardless of what server his copy was initially registered with.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot to say he is going to buy from the European site, in euros, he is gonna get an European Server account, get an european CDkey.

Comment: Oh, cool! Then yeah, in that case you'll be fine -- the only concern might be some latency.